# Xamarin Forms Switch toggles block ui

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I currently trying to implement two linked **Switch** element.
When one is toggled the other is untoggled.

But when my event is triggered, the clicked **Switch** do not finish is toggled.

The XAML :

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <Switch x:Name="WomanGenderSwitch" IsToggled="true"  Toggled="HandleWomanToggled" Scale="0.5">
                    </Switch>
                    <Label FontSize="12" x:Name="WomanSwitchLabel" TextColor="#ddd" VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                    </Label>
                    <Switch x:Name="ManGenderSwitch" Toggled="HandleManToggled" Scale="0.5">
                    </Switch>
                    <Label FontSize="12" x:Name="ManSwicthLabel" TextColor="#ddd" VerticalTextAlignment="Center">
                    </Label>
                </StackLayout>
```

Code Behind :

```
void HandleManToggled(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ToggledEventArgs e)
        {
            var s = sender as Switch;
            if (s.IsToggled)
                WomanGenderSwitch.IsToggled = false;
            else
                WomanGenderSwitch.IsToggled = false;
        }



  void HandleWomanToggled(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ToggledEventArgs e)
    {
        var s = sender as Switch;
        if (s.IsToggled)
            ManGenderSwitch.IsToggled = false;
        else
            ManGenderSwitch.IsToggled = false;
    }
```

Comment: can you also put _HandleWomanToggled_ event handler code ?

Comment: @ParsaKarami done :)

Comment: so why you need `if (s.IsToggled)` statement when if true or false the code runs `ManGenderSwitch.IsToggled = false;`?

Comment: @AkashKava Is not appropriated comment. If i'm not using MVVM is because i'm not able to use it according to specification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can re-use the same Handler for both Switches and since toggling the other Switch will cause its handler to be invoked you need to disable it otherwise you end up with a **non-ending event ripple**:

#### XAML:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <Switch x:Name="WomanGenderSwitch" IsToggled="true"  Toggled="HandleToggled" Scale="0.5" />
    <Label FontSize="12" x:Name="WomanSwitchLabel" TextColor="#ddd" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
    <Switch x:Name="ManGenderSwitch" Toggled="HandleToggled" Scale="0.5" />
    <Label FontSize="12" x:Name="ManSwicthLabel" TextColor="#ddd" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
</StackLayout>
```

#### Remove/Re-add handler to break event chain:

```
void HandleToggled(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ToggledEventArgs e)
{
    var aSwitch = ((sender == WomanGenderSwitch) ? ManGenderSwitch : WomanGenderSwitch);
    aSwitch.Toggled -= HandleToggled;
    aSwitch.IsToggled = !aSwitch.IsToggled;
    aSwitch.Toggled += HandleToggled;
}
```

#### Or using a flag to break the event chain:

```
bool busy;
void HandleToggled(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ToggledEventArgs e)
{
    if (busy == true) return;
    busy = true;
    var aSwitch = ((sender == WomanGenderSwitch) ? ManGenderSwitch : WomanGenderSwitch);
    aSwitch.IsToggled = !aSwitch.IsToggled;
    busy = false;
}
```

Comment: I will try this and mark as answer if it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

As Parsa said, your code does the same think regardless of IsToggled.

Try something like this:

```
void HandleManToggled(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ToggledEventArgs e)
        {
            var s = sender as Switch;
            if (s !=  null)
            {
                WomanGenderSwitch.IsToggled = s.IsToggled == false;
            }
        }



  void HandleWomanToggled(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ToggledEventArgs e)
    {
        var s = sender as Switch;
        if (s !=  null)
        {
            ManGenderSwitch.IsToggled = s.IsToggled == false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can not do that as you will end up with a non-ending event chain, you have to break the event chain somehow (removing the handler temporarily or use a flag to break the chain)