# Toggle event handler not creating

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I m working on a Xamarin forms application using visual studio 2017 , I want to uncheck a toggle  without firing the  Handle_Toggled event .I tried to create event by `userToggle.IsToggled +=`  and press press tab button twice but it didn't generate the event . I tried this code inside the constructor .

Comment: The usual way around this is to have a global `isLoading` Boolean variable, which you can keep enable while programmatically setting your controls, and then you just make all listeners check that Boolean and abort right away if it's set to `true`.

Comment: `Switch.IsToggled` is not an `EventHandler`, it is a `bool` property

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45727941/4984832

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks your answer helped me